# Oracle Apex: Create traffic lights in report based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive report with a startdate, enddate and the difference between those days.

Now I want to include a "traffic light" based on the **difference between the days**. 
Thats means if the difference is negative I want a red light, is it greater than 0 I want a green light.

Is there an easy way how to implement this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to paint the difference number (let's presume that it is called `DIFF`), for example

```
select 
  case when diff < 0 then '<span style="background-color:red;   color:white;">' || diff ||'</span>'
       else               '<span style="background-color:green; color:white;">' || diff ||'</span>'
  end traffic_light
from your_table
```

Comment: i know, but i was more thinking about doing it with svg. But thanks for the input

Comment: svg? What is "svg"?

Comment: Thank you, @Jeffrey. Well, I've (obviously) never used SVG. I know how to do that by displaying green/red *images* (such as *static workspace files*). If it helps, I can provide an example, but for SVG you (theGrandOracle) will have to wait for someone else's assistance.

Comment: To be fair, the OP's question never asked about implementing the traffic light as SVG; and regardless, your answer does answer the question, it's up to the OP to decide what markup to put in the html code generated by the query, whether a `span`, an `img`, or some `svg`.